# How to make sure that all the UI elements were the same size on all screens in new Unity 4.6 UI system

Tags: c#, unity, gui, ui-design

I have made a HUD for my 2d mobile game with the help of the new UI system, that was introduced in Unity 4.6. But when I am trying to play game in Unity editor, the UI elements have normal size, but when I am playing this game on mobile devices, they have more small size than in editor. Why this is happening? May be I missed something while watching Unity tutorials about new UI system. Can anyone help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Canvas Scaler](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-CanvasScaler.html) has a property called Ui Scale Mode, just select the option **Constant Physical Size**

[image: Unity Inspector Canvas Scaler Ui Scale Mode Constant Physical Size]

Comment: This is exactly what i needed!!! Thank you very much!!